# Is there a way to import a list of files in a DropBox folder into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, dropbox

I'm trying to import a list of subfolders and files from DropBox to Google Sheets. I really have no idea how to do this, I tried using

```
=importxml("folder"//a/@href")
```

but this doesn't seem to work for DropBox

any suggestions on a function I can try? I don't need the code, but if you can point me in the direction of which function I should read up on, I would appreciate it.

Comment: you will need a script for this

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to get one file at a time so I created a Chooser at the [DropBox App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) and you have to give it the url that your coming from and you can get that because it's part of the error message that is generated when you haven't provided one.  It's pretty much like a standard upload.

This is my GS code:

```
function dbxFileUpload(files) {
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(getGlobal('GPSTracksFolderId'));
  var fileBlob=UrlFetchApp.fetch(files[0].link).getBlob();
  var file=fldr.createFile(fileBlob);
  var fi=formatFileName(file);
  var fileInfo={'name':fi.getName(),'type':fileBlob.getContentType(), 'size':fileBlob.getBytes(), 'folder':fldr.getName(), 'id':fi.getId()};
  return fileInfo;
}
```

'files' is just the form Object from an input type=file.  I don't think this is exactly what you want but I'm hoping it will take you in the right direction. By the way, this will not work on Chrome.  I have to use Safari.